# Use of undeclared type 'WKInterfacePicker' - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, watchos

I am currently working on a project including iOS App and WatchOS App. App's Deployment target is 8.0 and I'm working on WatchOS 1. After correctly setting up the connection between iOS App and WatchOS App (via NSUserDefaults)(I've checked it using simple watch label updated on button tap) I encountered a problem: 'Use of undeclared type: ..." error comes up while trying to run the app. Same thing happens for various outlets: WKInterfaceActivityRing, WKInterfacePicker, etc. Target of my InterfaceController is set to WatchKit 1 Extension. Is there any reason of this happening? Unfortunately, I've already tried all solutions presented on StackOverflow and they don't work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `WKInterfacePicker` and `WKInterfaceActivityRing` aren't available in watchOS 1

Comment: Ok. Now everything is clear. Thanks a lot